# Xamarin iOS simulator - Error "The device was not found"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I am working on VS and remotely accessing the Mac agent. which is in the same network with my VS.

A deployment on actual device connected to the mac is working properly.

A deployment or running on simulator is giving me error:

[image: Error message]

I already looked lots of solution on the net but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: what do u mean ??

Answer (score 1):

After so many Trials: I found the solution. I am giving the solution incase if someone have faced same problem like mine. Since the VS is accessing all iOS related things from the remotely conencted Mac, making sure that the Xcode is updated will keep the VS from getting error msgs. I  have updated my Xcode and restarted my MAc. Then it has worked like a champ.